# Boundary of set on relative topology in $R^n$

Tags: general-topology

Let A be a subset of $R^n$ with the relative topology, let B be a subset of A,

is the boundary of B in the relative topology on A equal to the intersection of A with the boundary in $R^n$?
and mathematically: $ \partial_A B = A \cap \partial B  $ ?

the definition I use for boundary is:
$ \partial B = \bar{B} \cap \bar{B^c}  $

there is a way to prove that without prove inclusion of both sides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x \in \partial_{A}B$, then the ball $b^{x}(r)$ of center $x$ and radius $r$ is such that $b^{x}(r) \cap B \cap (A - B) \neq \varnothing$ for all $r > 0$; note that $A - B = (\mathbb{R}^{n} - B) \cap A$; so $x \in \partial B \cap A$. Conversely, if $x \in \partial B \cap A$, then $b^{x}(r) \cap B \cap (\mathbb{R}^{n} - B) \cap A \neq \varnothing$ for all $r > 0$; we have $(\mathbb{R}^{n} - B) \cap A = A - B$; it then follows that $x \in \partial_{A}B$.