# Relative Topology in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, multivariable-calculus

I'm studying relative topology for the first time and I've come across a proposition which states if $V \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is non empty and $A \subseteq V$ $$ \partial_v A = \partial A \cap V.$$  The proposition is clearly false if you take $A=V$ and $V$ closed then, $\partial_v V \subseteq \text{cl}_V(V - V)=\emptyset.$ Whereas, $\partial V$ is certainly not empty.

The following is a proof on someone elses question [Boundary of set on relative topology in $R^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1463323/boundary-of-set-on-relative-topology-in-rn). This doesn't work either, I've proven it for the case that $V$ is open, is that the only case that it holds for all $A \subset V$ (I know it is for $A \subseteq V$)?

Comment: It may be that a key word or phrase (e.g. V is open) was accidentally omitted from the book.

Answer (score 1):

Denote closure in $V$ by $Cl_V$ and closure in the ambient space $X$ (here $X = \mathbb{R}^n$) by $Cl_X$. Similarly for interior by $Int_V, Int_X$. Then $\partial_V A = Cl_V(A) - Int_V(A)$ and $\partial_X A = Cl_X(A) - Int_X(A)$. It is then sufficient to prove your proposition that $Cl_V(A) = Cl_X(A) \cap V$ and $Int_V(A) = Int_X(A) \cap V = Int_X(A)$.

$Cl_V(A)$ is precisely $A$ union its limit points in $V$. Thus it is sufficient to show that the set of limit points of $A$ in $V$ is equal to the set of limit points of $A$ in $X$ intersect $V$. The forward inclusion $\subseteq$ is clear. Suppose $x \in V$ is a limit point of $V$ in $X$. Let $U$ an open set in $V$ containing $x$. Then $U = B \cap V$ where $B$ is an open set in $X$ containing $x$. Then $B \cap A \backslash \{x\} \neq \emptyset$ as $x$ is a limit point of $A$ in $X$. Then $A \subseteq V$ so $U \cap A \backslash\{x\} = V \cap B \cap A \backslash\{x\} = B \cap A \backslash \{x\} \neq \emptyset$. So $x$ is a limit point of $A$ in $V$, so we get the backwards inclusions $\supseteq$. Thus $Cl_V(A) = Cl_X(A) \cap V$.

Edit: I realize I've made a mistake. The proposition certainly doesn't hold in general, since in general $Int_V(A) \supseteq Int_X(A)$ (as can be easily checked), but the reverse containment doesn't hold. So the best you can hope for in general is $\partial_V A \subseteq \partial_X A$

Edit 2: I just looked at the proof in the book OP mentioned. The authors make the argument:
$$\partial_V A = (V \cap Cl_{\mathbb{R}^n}(A)) \cap (V \cap Cl_{\mathbb{R}^n}(V \backslash A)) = (V \cap Cl_{\mathbb{R}^n}(A)) \cap (V \cap Cl_{\mathbb{R}^n} ({\mathbb{R}^n} \backslash A)) = \cdots$$
But this is wrong: $V \cap Cl_{\mathbb{R}^n}(V \backslash A)) \neq V \cap Cl_{\mathbb{R}^n} ({\mathbb{R}^n} \backslash A)$ in general. E.g. if $V$ is the closed unit ball.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, so you have assumed there exists such an open $U \subset V$ hence $x$ is not in $\partial V$ so for you're argument to work $A \cap \partial V$ has to be empty (for fixed $A$)? And in general for it to work for all $A \subset V$, $V$ has to be open?

Comment: I did not assume the existence of an open in $X$ (again here $X= \mathbb{R}^n$ but really all this is true in general topological spaces so restricting to $\mathbb{R}^n $ is unnecessary and likely to hurt rather than help) set $U$ s.t. $U \subseteq V$. This is the whole point of relative topology. There is a notion of open in $X$ and a notion of open in $V$. $U$ is open in $V$.

Comment: You said "Let $U$ be an open subset in $V$ containing $x$" which implies $x$ is not in the boundary set of V?

Comment: Open in $V$. Not open in $X$. Let $V = [0,1]$. Then $V$ has boundary in $\mathbb{R}$ of $\{0,1\}$. But $U:= V$ is open in $V$.

Comment: Whats wrong with my counter-example then?

Comment: Yeah, you're actually right. I made a silly mistake. See the edit, the proposition certainly doesn't hold in general, in fact by the above argument it holds iff $\int_V(A) = \int_X(A)$. So you can think about conditions under which that holds. For example if $V$ is open.

Comment: The Proposition is from the first chapter of Multidimensional real analysis (1.2.17) by 
J.J. Duistermaat, it's been driving me crazy the past few days, you don't expect books to be wrong so you think it must be you.

Comment: Check the new edit. Weird how wrong the book is.